# Get vertex as single array

Tags: python, api, maya

I need to get all the selected vertices and store them in an array so I can loop through and find out information about each vert.

Although I cannot figure this out.

```
sel = cmds.ls(sl=1)
print sel
```

Returns:

```
//[u'pCube1.vtx[50:53]', u'pCube1.vtx[74:77]']
```

More or less I need my 'sel' variable to print out this:

```
pCube1.vtx[50]
pCube1.vtx[51]
pCube1.vtx[52]
pCube1.vtx[53]
pCube1.vtx[74]
pCube1.vtx[75]
pCube1.vtx[76]
pCube1.vtx[77]
```

Does anyone know how to do this without literally stripping the string apart? I think that's a very messy way around it and would like to know if there's another possibility! Maybe with the Maya API using OpenMaya?

Comment: In search of this, and after posting this, I very soon found an answer..... `cmds.ls(sl=1, fl=1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it seems research has paid off!

```
cmds.ls(sl=1, fl=1)
```

the 'fl' flag stands for "Flatten", Flatten returns a list of objects so that each component is identified individually.

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering your own question, but perhaps you can expand on what you learned that made that the solution.

Comment: That's a good idea too, thankyou @JasonSperske, I have expanded my answer.